# gnuplot cuts off fractional digits

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot some stockpile data.
The data is located in a csv-file and I already got an almost accurate plot, so reading from file isn't the problem.

```
set terminal pdf
set output "gnuplot/".MATNUM."-2012.pdf"

set datafile separator ";"

stats 'Stock-2012.csv' every ::4::18 using MATNUM nooutput

set border 3
set tics nomirror
set xzeroaxis

set xrange[0:14]
set xtics 1,1,13
set xtics rotate 90

set ylabel MATUNIT

maxplot = sprintf("Amount max:\n%.2f ".MATUNIT, STATS_max)
plot 'Stock-2012.csv' every ::4::18 using ($0+1):MATNUM:xticlabels(2) with linespoints title "Amount", STATS_max with lines lc rgb 'blue' title maxplot
```

Where MATNUM and MATUNIT are commandline arguments, representing materialnumber (which is the columntitle in the datafile) and the unit in which the material is measured.

The x-values in my datafile are decimals, but gnuplot seems to cut off the fractional digits. For example 12,98 (commata are used as decimal separator, because it's a german stockpile) results in a datapoint at y=12.
I'm not sure but I think this happens only at the maximum and minimum y-value, as STATS_max is an integer every time.

What can I do to get my points at the right y-value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you did not show any data from you file, but I guess you are using commas as decimal separators. In that case you need to set the right decimal sign for reading the input. You can use e.g.

```
set decimalsign locale
```

or use an explicit locale (this must be installed)

```
set decimalsign locale "de_DE.UTF-8"
```

Note, that setting an explicit character with `set decimalsign ','` does not work because it usually affects only the output format of e.g. tics, but not the input behaviour.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is great! But the variable 'maxplot' still contains the cut off version.

Comment: Thanks, found it. Extra thanks for adding information on specifying amount of fractional digits