# Saving gretl data in a .txt to plot with gnuplot causes problems due to scientific notation. How can I circumvent that?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm very new to the software so apologies if the question is redundant. Couldn't find the exact solution to my problem.

I got a stata file (.dta) which I'm accessing with gretl. However, the plotting through the gretl interface is very limited so I want to directly use gnuplot.

I have no idea how to access the .dta file with gnuplot so I saved some variables from gretl in .txt files to try to plot them. Unfortunately though it then reads for example 5,86696e-005 as a value of 5,xxx and not as a number between 0 and 1. So even though all the data stored in the variables should be between 0 and 1, I get some values of 9 or 5.

Also the data is comma separated because it's european data. Maybe that is the problem?

Thanks for the help

Comment: The problem comes from the comma as decimal sign in your input data: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18186919/2604213

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was indeed the problem.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how exactly you produced the .txt file with the decimal comma from Gretl. Because AFAIK Gretl only exports with decimal commas if explicitly being told to do that, even if it is running in a locale-setting with native decimal commas.