# GnuPlot - 2D chart doesn't mark double values

Tags: charts, gnuplot

I work with GnuPlot: https://github.com/AwokeKnowing/GnuplotCSharp

Here is my code:

`double[] Yt = new double[] { -2.5, 10.5, -0.6, 8.4, 4.7, -2.21, 12.65, 4.58, 6.77, -3.21 };
GnuPlot.Plot(Yt);`

Here is generated 2D chart:
[2D chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9jZr.png)

The problem is that values in the array are not integers, but on the chart was marked as they were integers. How can I mark double values on the chart?

Comment: I guess you are hitting https://github.com/AwokeKnowing/GnuplotCSharp/pull/3

Comment: How can it help me? @Christoph

Comment: That means: It is a bug in GnuplotCSharp which is not fixed

Comment: This is way out of my area of expertise, but it sounds like the bug comes from the fact that GnuplotCSharp turns a floating point value like 10.5 into a string representation that gnuplot doesn't understand by default, like "10,5" (note the comma). What locale are you in? You either have to prevent the conversion to a locale-specific string by setting the environment for your program, or you have to make gnuplot aware that it should interpret strings to numbers in this locale-specific way. The latter you can do by send gnuplot a `set decimalsign` command.

Comment: @user8153 You are right, a `set decimalsign locale` could work (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18186919/2604213), i.e. `GnuPlot.Set("decimalsign locale")` for the c# wrapper.

Comment: `GnuPlot.Set("decimalsign locale")` works like a charm. Thank you guys. You can add answer and I'll mark it as best.