# Gnuplot boxplot information

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

I don't know gnuplot so much and I didn't find valuable information about what I want. I would like to draw a box plot from a data file.

- What is the format of the file?
- Is it needed to compute mean, qc etc.?

What I would like to do is to draw a boxplot (not an histogram). Actually I have xlsx files that I can convert to CSV but I don't know if we can use csv to draw a boxplot.
The demos on gnuplot are not really explicit.

Comment: By "drawing a box" do you mean you wish to plot you file as a histogram? Also, how can we know the format of your file when we don't know what it is! Please post some code/more words to clarify what you want to accomplish

Comment: A boxplot is a boxplot, I can't be more precise. And for the file I have added what I have so far, but I am actually asking for information because I don't know what to use.

Comment: The documentation is quite explicit about the format to use: Use e.g `plot "file" u (1):2 with boxplot` to plot the data in the second column as boxplot at x=1. All necessary value are computed by gnuplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of a boxplot:

```
$data <<EOD
1
2
3
4
5
6
EOD

plot $data using (0):1 with boxplot
```

This does a boxplot using the values given in column 1, all statistical values are computed by gnuplot, and plots it at x-position 0. (`$data` is only a convenient way to describe inline data, plotting from a file with a single column work the same way with `plot 'file.dat' using (0):1 with boxplot`)

You can use as many columns as you want, like

```
$data <<EOD
1 1 1
2 2 4
3 3 5
4 3 5
5 4 6
6 6 6
EOD

set style data boxplot
plot $data using (0):1, '' using (1):2, '' using (2):3
```

(shorter would be `plot for [i=1:3] $data using (i-1):i`)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how you can handle floats? It seems that it causes trouble to gnuplot.

Comment: The only thing that could go wrong with floats in data is the decimal separator. Use `.` or `set decimalsign locale`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18186919/2604213

Comment: Thanks a lot I have figured out the pb. However, do you know how could I add a title to the line using a for loop? The title is repeated a number equivalent to the loop size and I am having hard time to avoid this.